# Merge two lists in scala using AND condition

Tags: scala, list

Can someone suggest the best way to merge two lists in scala so that the resulting list will only contain matching elements in both lists?

Example:

```
  List[Int] = List(10,20,30)
  List[Int] = List(30,50)
  Result: List[Int] = List(30)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**And condition (nested for loop)**

You can use *nested for loops* as

```
val list1 = List(10, 20, 30)
val list2 = List(30, 50)

val result = for(value1 <- list1; value2 <- list2; if value1 == value2) yield value1

println(result)
```

which would print `List(30)`

**Intersect() (built-in function)**

You can use `intersect` function which will give you *common values in both lists* as

```
println(list1.intersect(list2))
```

which should give you `List(30)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was looking for an inbuilt function and intersect solved my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the intersect solution, you can also use an `filter` with a `contains` inside

```
l1.filter(l2.contains(_))
```

With your input:

```
l1: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30)
l2: List[Int] = List(30, 50)
```

Result will be:

```
List[Int] = List(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar functionality can be achieved with `dropwhile` or `takeWhile` also

```
scala> l2.takeWhile(l1.contains(_))
res8: List[Int] = List(30)

scala> l1.dropWhile(!l2.contains(_))
res10: List[Int] = List(30)
```